# ¿Cómo usar @Autowired en un atributo estático?

Tags: java, spring-boot, controller, interface, inyeccion-de-dependencias

**Buenas a todos**.

Estoy usando Java con el JDK 17.0.5, en mi programa tengo una clase Util que sirve para validar códigos de productos (Business Logic), el cual es una clase Final. En la misma, utilizo una inyección de dependencia a través de una anotación Autowired que inyecta una interfaz de servicios. Luego, existe el método que valida los códigos y que, dentro suyo, se utiliza la interfaz para hacer una búsqueda a través del repositorio.

```
    @Autowired
    ProductCodeService productCodeService;

    public boolean isPresent(Long id, TypeProductLog code){

        ProductCode productId = productCodeService.findPCById(id);
        ProductCode productCode = productCodeService.findPCByCode(code);

        return (productId != null || productCode != null);
    }
```

El problema es que cuando quiero definir ese método con la keyword Static, me obliga a declarar la inyección de la interfaz de la misma manera. Entiendo que en contexto Static solo puede utilizar variables Static, pero al declarar el Autowired como Static me da `null`.

```
@Autowired
static ProductCodeService productCodeService;
```

La finalidad de esta clase Util es usarlo dentro de un método de una clase Controller, la cual, dentro de su lógica, debe validar si un nuevo código de producto ya existe dentro de la BD.

```
@PostMapping("/qualities")
public ResponseEntity<Object> createQC(@RequestParam String code, @RequestParam Long id,
                                       @RequestParam(required = false) String description){

    if (qualityCodeValidator.isPresent(id, code)){
        //Expressions
    }
    if (qualityCodeValidator.isInvalid(id, code)){
        //Expressions
    }
```

}

Desde ya, muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: El código es texto, trátalo como tal. No toda la gente puede ver imágenes ni toda la gente puede ver correctamente el esquema de colores que a ti te gusta. Sabes lo que si puede ver todo el mundo? EL TEXTO! Usa el enlace [edit] y pon el código **como texto**. De paso te explico algo que parece que estás ignorando pese a que tú mismo lo has dicho... cuando usas un servicio `@autowired` spring-boot te inyecta una versión instanciada de dicho servicio. Un método estático no se utiliza desde una instancia de un objeto con lo cual **NO TIENE ACCESO** a las variables de instancia.

Comment: Si de verdad quieres hacer el método estático, necesitarás ponerle como parámetro el propio servicio que va a usar: `public static boolean isPresent(Long id, String code, ProductCodeService service)`. De todas maneras no hay ningún problema en instanciar una clase de utils en springboot, todos los componentes de springboot en general se tratan como singletons y siempre que si inyectan te da la misma instancia (a no ser que se especifique de otra manera), con lo cual no es mucho peor que instanciar un servicio más.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta pero no hacía falta la agresividad para responder. Soy nuevo en el sector y estoy aprendiendo. Tenía una duda y claramente me faltan conceptos que aprender, pero no es motivo para esa forma de responder. Ojalá no toda comunidad tenga está misma actitud tóxica.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podrias comentarme que parte te parecio agresiva? no te dieron una respuesta, te dejaron un comentario, preo no veo que parte es agresiva...

Comment: recuerda que Java cambia con el tiempo, así que te sugiero que especifiques la versión

Comment: Ya modifique el post para que sea más entendible para todos. Gracias por las aclaraciones!.

Comment: Cuando modifiques tu pregunta acuérdate de adecuar el título también. Es importante que el título describa lo más explicitamente posible la pregunta para que otros puedan encontrarla. No solo sirve para que quien vaya a responderte sepa de qué va la pregunta, si no también para que se encuentre fácil cuando buscas tu problema en google!

Answer (score 1):

Primero que nada quisiera aclarar que es mejor no hacer lo que estoy a punto de hacer en esta respuesta, puesto que, *AUNQUE FUNCIONE* **NO TIENES GARANTÍAS DE QUE UN CAMPO ESTÁTICO HA SIDO CORRECTAMENTE INICIALIZADO**. Dicho eso, *debería* de funcionar correctamente... pero el riesgo no vale la pena, especialmente si lo que vas a hacer es una aplicación seria.

Habiendo explicado por qué no debe hacerse, he aquí el cómo hacer lo que no debe hacerse:

```java
@Component
public class Utils {
  // Atributo estático
  @Autowired
  private static ProductCodeService productCodeService; // Siempre private, recordemos la encapsulación
  
  // Atributo no estático
  @Autowired
  private ProductCodeService productCodeService;


  /*
   * Este método anotado con @PostConstruct se ejecutará automáticamente en cuanto spring 
   * instancie la clase, asignando el servicio de la instancia al atributo estático
   */
  @PostConstruct
   private void init() {
      productCodeService = this.productCodeService;
   }
}
```

Repito lo que dije más arriba... nadie te garantiza que cuando llames a un método que vaya a usar tus atributos estáticos esta clase esté ya construida e inicializada... **esto puede dar lugar a errores *y no debería hacerse en código de producción***